# MVC4 style bundle giving 403

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

When bundling/minification is enabled, some of my bundles seem to have an invalid URL in the browser (ending with a /), and IIS gives a 403 forbidden error, as if trying to list a folder's contents.

There's no difference in the way my bundles are set up - they are not .min.css, access permissions are correct etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC framework 4.5 CSS bundles does not work on the hosting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081255/asp-net-mvc-framework-4-5-css-bundles-does-not-work-on-the-hosting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC framework 4.5 CSS bundles does not work on the hosting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081255/asp-net-mvc-framework-4-5-css-bundles-does-not-work-on-the-hosting)

Answer (score 244, accepted):

My bundles were registered as paths which corresponded to an actual folder on the solution, e.g. `~/Content/forum`.

This works fine when bundling is turned off (the bundle is included correctly!), but not when bundling is enabled.

The solution is to change the registered name of the bundle to not be the same as anything that exists in the file system.

Comment: Note also if the CSS files refer to imagery or other files relative to the CSS, make sure the bundle filename is something *under* the folder containing the actual CSS.  For example, `~/Content/myfolder/bundle` if CSS is under `Content/myfolder`

Comment: I had two bundles: ~/Content/kendo (for css) and ~/bundles/kendo (for scripts). So: 403 error. When I changed name one of them - problem gone. Thanks.

Comment: what exatcly do you mean the name of the bundle itself?

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle - are you asking me?  I don't use that phrase anywhere

Comment: @KierenJohnstone sorry about not being specific, `"Change the registered name of the bundle"` what do you mean with that? - I assumed the name of the bundle **WE** assign. Like (the bolded part) -> `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle(` **"~/Content/css"** `).Include("~/Content/site.css"));`

Comment: my bundle name was "~/Content/css" and a directory /Content/css already existed.  I changed the bundle name to "~/Content/cssScripts" and it was all good.

Comment: Spot on. This seems to be a bug in the FontAwesome nuget package.

Comment: Also in the select2 nuget package.

Comment: This solved a lot of headache for me. @WolfyUK is correct. The bug still persists in 2018/19...

Comment: This is what worked for me "The solution is to change the registered name of the bundle to not be the same as anything that exists in the file system."

Answer (score 4):

In my case bundle was specified as a directory `@Scripts.Render("~/scripts")` so IIS did not know how to serve the actual js file, I changed the bundle name to represent a javascript file `@Scripts.Render("~/scripts.js")` and that fixed it. The same was true for my style bundle.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the naming convention your bundle name should be

```
("bundles/css")
```

This solved my problem.