# Why can not load All Js and Css in a Folder ? in mvc 5 bundles

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I want know why can not load All Js and Css a folder ?
i have a folder for front views  `FrontTheme` in this folder there is 2 folders `css` and `js` and i want load all js and css files in `FrontTheme` folder in bundles

my code is :

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
    //    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/Admin/js").IncludeDirectory("~/Content/Admin/assets/", "*.js",true));
      //  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Admin/css").IncludeDirectory("~/Content/Admin/assets/", "*.css",true));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/FrontTheme/js")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Content/FrontTheme/js", "*.js",true));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/FrontTheme/css")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Content/FrontTheme/css", "*.css",false));


#if DEBUG
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
#else
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
```

and in view i use:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/FrontTheme/js")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/FrontTheme/css")
```

but bundles not load css and js files and browser get me 403 forbidden status.

Where is it wrong?
[image: codes]
[image: statuscode]

---Update---
even i change bundles name to

`~/Content/FrontThemejs`

`~/FrontTheme/js`

`~/FrontThemejs`

`~/Frontjs`

`Frontjs`

`~/123/js`

`~/Content/FrontThemecss`

`~/FrontTheme/css`

`~/FrontThemecss`

`~/Frontcss`

`Frontcss`

`~/456/css`

but status code from `403` change to `404`

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC4 style bundle giving 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673759/mvc4-style-bundle-giving-403)

Comment: As noted in @adiga's link, don't use a real folder name (`~/Content`) for the name of your bundle.  It will cause these types of issues.

Comment: @stephen.vakil i change name to `~/FrontTheme/css` but same problem even change to `~/FrontThemecss` then error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Probably needs to have the same depth in the folder structure.  Try `~/ScriptBundle/FrontTheme/js` and `~/StyleBundle/FrontTheme/css` maybe.  Just a guess.

Comment: @stephen.vakil Doesn't work