# Can Not Get Css to render with ASP.NET MVC4 ScriptBundling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I've got an app I started with ASP.NET MVC4 WebAPI project.  somehow, my css is not getting rendered when I have BundleTable.EnableOptimizations Defaulted (which is true).  When I set it to false (in my RegisterBundles.cs) file, the web site renders correctly.

What I'm seeing in my network traffic (which is failing with an http status 403, forbidden.

```
http://localhost:17138/Content/Styles/?v=xz2jRv8a4HMY4rDzixZn1RlC6AERf9qY0Gh7MavTpZE1
```

I keep comparing this to a default empty new project which works and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

THanks

Comment: Why would you be using anything CSS related when using a WebAPI project. Do you mean a standard web site template?

Comment: @Nick I assume it's both an MVC site and web api, which is possible.  Is that right Peter?

Comment: yes, same project.  it uses the webapi template but it creates the full controller suite.  In App_Start is BundleConfig,FilterConfig,RouteConfig AND WebApiConfig

Comment: True Brian.  It feels like the bundler is buggy but maybe I'm missing something.  It's not critical right now and summit is 2 weeks away so I'm sure I can get help there if I don't figure it by then.

Answer (score 2):

See this link, which suggests that the issue is with the /Content/Styles folder existing in your project:  [ASP.NET MVC framework 4.5 CSS bundles does not work on the hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081255/asp-net-mvc-framework-4-5-css-bundles-does-not-work-on-the-hosting)

As the answer there suggested, since the folder exists on disk, IIS handles the request.

Comment: Nice try, but not my problem.  Content/Styles does not exist in my project.