# Upgraded dotLess error: IImporter does not contain definition for 'Paths'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5, dotless

I have the following code in a project I try to upgrade the **["dotless" NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotless/)** from the "1.2.2.0" to the latest (at moment "1.4.0.0"):

```
private void GetStylesheetContent(HttpContext context, string name)
{
    var conf = BundleConfigSectionHandler.GetConfig();
    var elt = conf.Stylesheets.GetBundle(name); 
    if (elt != null) {
        Minifier minifier = null;
        if (_conf.Stylesheets.Minify) {
            minifier = new Minifier();
        }    
        var files = elt.ListFiles();
        var existingFiles = new List<string>();    
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var file in files) {
            var physicalFile = context.Request.MapPath(file);
            if (File.Exists(physicalFile)) {
                existingFiles.Add(physicalFile);                        
                string content;
                var path = VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(file);
                if (file.EndsWith(".less", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
                {
                    var reader = new dotless.Core.Input.VirtualFileReader();
                    var localpath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(file);
                    content = reader.GetFileContents(localpath);
                    var parse = new Parser();
                    parse.Importer = new Importer(reader);

        /*Error>*/ parse.Importer.Paths.Add(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(path));

                    var eng = new LessEngine(parse);
                    content = eng.TransformToCss(content, localpath);
```

The error is on the third line from bottom. It says:

> Error 417 '**dotless.Core.Importers.IImporter**' does not contain a
>   definition for '**Paths**' and no extension method 'Paths' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'dotless.Core.Importers.IImporter' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is a pity that the team didn't left the old method with an [Obsolete] attribute and suggestion to upgrade. 
Does anyone know how to replace the "Importer.Paths.Add" method ?

Comment: I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but we're moving away from dotless in favor of just compiling the less dusting a build (e.g. on our staging server). Probably more work on the bundles, but until/unless dotless catches up with less js, it's hard to justify using it. So that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with the inner workings of dotless. But looking at [the source code](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/blob/master/src/dotless.Core/Importers/Importer.cs) for the Importer. `paths` has been `protected` since version version 1.2.3. Looking around at the class a little more, it seems like you need to use an instance of [`dotless.Parser.Tree.Import`](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/blob/master/src/dotless.Core/Parser/Tree/Import.cs) to add your paths manually.

It does look like this is pretty far off the normal dotless path. So it wouldn't surprise me if the API is a little unstable in these areas. You also may want to look at how bundling works in a question like [How to use ASP.Net MVC 4 to Bundle LESS files in Release mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252829/how-to-use-asp-net-mvc-4-to-bundle-less-files-in-release-mode) to see how they handle all the dotless classes.

Comment: I tried just for test to do `parse.Importer.Imports.Add(...);` to compile the project. but not tested yet (and actually have no clear idea how to test)