# LESS files intermittently not being included in Bundle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, dotless, system.web.optimization

In my ASP.NET MVC5 project I'm using [Bundling/Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) and [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) together.

```
var commonCss = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/main.css").Include(
                "~/CSS/global.css",
                "~/CSS/header.less",
                "~/CSS/footer.css"
                );

commonCss.Transforms.Clear();
commonCss.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());
commonCss.Transforms.Add(new ConfigurableStyleTransform(cssSettings));

return commonCss;
```

`LessTransform()` is from [System.Web.Optimization.Less](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Optimization.Less/).

Intermittently I'm seeing the `header.less` file not being included in the bundle. Sometimes it will, sometimes it won't, without any code changes.

I've ran the LESS file through a validator and no issues found.

The only other times I've seen a file not being included in a bundle is when the file cannot be found, or theres a syntax issue. However this doesn't seem applicable for this instance.

What possible reasons are there for this file not being included in the bundle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15252829/880709

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? We're seeing this issue intermittently as well.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung Unfortunately no. We switched over to using VS Web Essentials to pre-compile to CSS. To be fair this is actually a better solution as theres no on-the-fly conversion each time the CSS is requested.

Answer (score 1):

You might be hitting [this bug in dotless](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/418). If that's the case, until it gets fixed, you can get around it by specifying `disableParameters="true"` in the `dotless` section of your Web.config.