# MVC bundeling : Err 403

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, web-deployment, bundling-and-minification, kendo-asp.net-mvc

*Using VS'12, Asp.net - C# - InternetApplication Template, KendoUI, EF Code First*

**This is my MVC `BundleConfig.cs`**

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

        // The Kendo CSS bundle
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo").Include(
                "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.*",
                "~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.*"));

        // The Kendo JavaScript bundle// or kendo.all.min.js if you want to use Kendo UI Web and Kendo UI DataViz
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
                                    "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.web.min.js",
                                    "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"));
```

**Also you should know that i am running these 2 lines at the end of `BundleConfig.cs`**

```
        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
        bundles.DirectoryFilter.Clear();
```

I have been getting **403 Access Denied** , File Forbidden Errors when I try to host the project.

I have tried to use [This Awesome Post](http://www.mvccentral.net/Story/Details/articles/kahanu/stylebundle-403-error-solved) as a reference, where I did change some things, but errors are still occuring.

*I would like to think its because of the .min files KendoUI came with, but i can't be certain.*

**For your reference this is my `_Layout.cshtml`, and how i call the scripts.**

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try changing

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo").Include(
            "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.*",
            "~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.*"));
```

to

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/kendo").Include(
            "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.*.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.*.css"));
```

and then

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo")
```

to

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css/kendo")
```

Comment: Freaking awesome, them both being in /Content was causing issues i guess?? - thanks for your quick reply also!

Comment: For those interested: using `~/Content` for the `StyleBundle` doesn't work, because it's already an existing folder.

Answer (score 4):

it's because you're using the same 'alias' (/Content/kendo) for the stylebundle as the already existing directory.

once you use another alias (/Content/css/kendo/ or /Content/whatevernonexistingdir) your problem is solved.

but be aware: the 'root' of the css is changed, so when using (background) images in your css which are pointing to subfolders, take this into account!