# BundleConfig err 403 - style and javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

it, so that now I can not get my style to be displayed on the page. it just comes up with this stuff in my html.

I've tried to look here
[MVC bundeling : Err 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474669/mvc-bundeling-err-403)

```
<link href="/Content/?v=QJxA7R8Re3uqMX1yrXXxo93tvLZiLQJPzVSY80tOo9s1" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/skins/?v=cvum26wsOdSFqp48CXFJ39rlGKOSzsCvOJZuuLeX4901" rel="stylesheet">
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/skins/")
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/skins/").Include(
                  "~/Content/skins/default.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/").Include(
                  "~/Content/theme.css",
                  "~/Content/theme-*"));
    }
```

It gives me this one error.
[image]

That's my folder here.

[image]

**EIDT (Update)**

BundleConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundle/skins").Include(
                  "~/Content/skins/default.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundle/Content")
            .Include("~/Content/theme.css")
            .Include("~/Content/theme-blog.css")
            .Include("~/Content/theme-animate.css")
            .Include("~/Content/theme-elements.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundle/Scripts")
            .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css")
            .Include("~/Scripts/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css")
            .Include("~/Scripts/owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css")
            .Include("~/Scripts/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css"));
    }
```

Layout.cshtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundle/Content")
@Styles.Render("~/bundle/skins")
@Styles.Render("~/bundle/Scripts")
```

Comment: Make sure your bundle names are **not** the same as an existing path.  For example, use `~/bundle/content` instead of `~/Content`.

Comment: @BrendanGreen It is both the Layout part or is it just Bundle part. Do you have an example of how it should look.

Comment: Just added an answer that shows a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the name that you have given the bundles are the same as an existing folder in your solution.

The fix is to change the name of your bundles so that they don't clash with existing folders.

For example, instead of `~/Content/skins` use `~/bundle/skins`:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundle/skins").Include(
              "~/Content/skins/default.css"));
}
```

Then:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundle/skins")
```

Comment: It gives me still error 403 on it you have sent me. :(

Comment: Can you post the updated code that you are using?  It might also be a cache problem - have you cleared the browser cache and refreshed?

Comment: Thanks for help. i have giv u a 1 point for its help! and i hope u will giv me a +1 for its.