# Access Forbidden error when BundleConfig is read

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, hosting

When I upload my MVC 4 project to my WebServer, I saw that all my CSS and JavaScript references that I put on BundleConfig wasn't loaded to the page, instead this, appears on my rendered page the following path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fw14/Content/css?v=kSepHHq11FdR1tRAJySyLFezI3fwYIn7a12kdamDI-w1">
```

In localhost works fine,

**BundleConfig**

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                        "~/fw14/Content/css/san.css",
                        "~/fw14/Content/css/bootstrap.css"
                        ));
```

My application are in

```
wwwroot/fw14/
```

When I open the `<link>` when is rendered, I can saw this

```
<h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
<h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
```

I think this weird, because I have permission to upload all my project, but the system can't saw the folders?

[image]

In my IIS, SislocPool is the name of my AppPool, and runs in NetworkService credentials

[image]

I also try put the following line in my Web.Config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Comment: Just because YOU have permission to upload doesn't mean the Worker Process does.  Your worker process runs under a different account with different credentials than you.

Comment: I agree. but now I give full access in my folder, but still the same. In thsi case, I give full access to my pool in IIS that uses localSystem credentials

Comment: Your IIS pool does not use local system credentials.  If it did, it could not access the network.  Typically, app pools use Network Service,or a local or domain user (not system).

Comment: Changed to NetworkService, I restart the pool, but still same error, forbidden access, and then, all my CSS files doesn't load.

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch , some time it has to do with bundle name and folder structure issue, so  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28231111/2218697) **answer** solved my issue. hope helps someone.