# Using bundles in WebForms outputs the minified/combined file even in debug mode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, web-optimization

I've created a bundle of various script files that I want to be combined/minified together.  In my code behind file (yes, sorry it's in VB!) I add it to a `<asp:placeholder />` on the `<head>` like this

```
Me.PlhHeader.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main").ToHtmlString()))
```

This will work, but it always seems to output the compressed minified version, even when `debug="true"` in the Web.Config.

no matter what, this is what is output: `<script src="/bundles/main"></script>`

What do I need to do differently to make this output the individual uncompressed files when in debug mode?

---

**EDIT**

I've also tried to manually set the option `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false` and it *still* outputs the single minified script tag.  I'm out of ideas.

---

## Final Edit

I was doing something very dumb with some related code, but technically everything with the bundles was fine and working correctly. Problem solved for me!

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944745/asp-net-bundles-how-to-disable-minification

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a duplicate (of that question anyway).  I just updated with a few more clarifications.

Comment: What version of .NET? 4?

Comment: We are using the latest, .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to install the Microsoft.AspNet.WebOptimization.WebForms. It works really well.

[Microsoft.AspNet.WebOptimization.WebForms](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms/)

Then you can use:

```
<%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main") %>
```

Comment: I already have this installed, which is how I'm able to create working bundles.  The problem I'm having is that I can never get it to use the *unbundled* files when in debug mode.

Comment: I get it ;) It should't bundle on Debug mode. Best thing to do is check the Publish Profiles on the project. I have experienced something similar when I didn't have the Script/Css files on the publish settings. Check this "not so up to date" solution I have done before the nuget package. It might point you in the right direction. [link](https://github.com/marcoramires/WebformsBoilerplate)

Comment: Also remove any obj/[debug][release]/packages/PackageTmp folder. MSBuild compiles your WebApplication on this folder before it publishes to the destination folder.