# Turn off bundling/minification while debugging in WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, bundle, minify, asp.net-optimization

I want to be able to minify/bundle my javascript files in a production environment while having them unminified/unbundled when debugging locally; however, the default WebForms site in VS2012 does not appear to allow for it.

Steps to reproduce my issue:

1. Create a new "ASP.NET Web Forms Application" (c# in my case)
2. Start without debugging and view resources in browser
3. Notice unminified jquery/modernizr files but bundled/minified `MsAjaxJS` and `WebFormsJs`

web.config, by default has:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```

And I've even tried modifying the Global.asax by explicitly telling `BundleTable` not to optimize:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Yet, I still get undebuggable javascript files:

[image: Chrome Dev tools (showing minified/bundled files)]

[This site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) (which I realize is for MVC) tells me that either `debug="true"` in the web.config or `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;` in Global.asax should turn off the functionality. And [this site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx), (which *is* for WebForms and is linked from the first), doesn't mention turning it off for debugging.

How might I (cleanly) tell my project to only minify/bundle when debug="false"?

(I'm using ASP.NET 4.5)

**EDIT:**
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069989/using-bundles-in-webforms-outputs-the-minified-combined-file-even-in-debug-mode?lq=1) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944745/asp-net-bundles-how-to-disable-minification) are similar, but they both only offer a solution using `Scripts.Render()`. Is there a way to accomplish this with the templated method of using the ScriptManager?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Did you ever resolve this with a ScriptManager?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Can you mark my answer below as 'Answer'?  I'd appreciate it greatly. :)

Answer (score 7):

Add the following code to your Global.asax.cs file in the Application_Start method.  This works perfectly for me.

```
#if DEBUG
       foreach (var bundle in BundleTable.Bundles)
       {
           bundle.Transforms.Clear();
       }
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue before. I solved my problem by putting this code

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

**after**

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```