# Debug javascript files associated with the respected .ascx in VS 2017/2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I have ASP.NET Website, not a web application, and it doesn't have bin\debug directory.

My project structure is as follows:

[image]

I am trying to debug .js files associated with the .ascx controllers, but can't debug them.
I always see the error `the breakpoint set but not yet bound`. I have tried almost all of the solutions on StackOverflow, like clean rebuild, then enabling\disabling debugging under Tools, but nothing has worked  so far.

Sample .ascx looks like

```
<eui:control id="contextAdministrator" codefile="/usercontrols/applications/administration/contextAdministrator.js" namespace="contextAdministrator" tabtitle="General">
    <input id="AccessibilityDetails" type="hidden" size="20" name="AccessibilityDetails" runat="server" />
```

Sample .js file looks like:

```
JSON
{
    Main: function() {

        var userControlIndexID = UI.ARManager.controls[this.id].userControlIndexID;

        var currentContextValue = null;

        var initialized = false;

        var panels = {};
        var maxPages = 15;
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: It's **much easier** to debug JavaScript directly in your web-browser (via DevTools) instead of trying to get Visual Studio's Chrome debugger to work.

Comment: VS's JavaScript debugger was originally meant for Internet Explorer and uses MSHTML's DCOM debugging system. It's a pain to get working (and Internet Explorer is irrelevant today anyway). I don't believe VS 2017 nor 2019 natively supports connecting to Chromium's JS debugger, I think you need an extension for that. I might be wrong with more recent versions of VS 2019 though.

Comment: The problem is I can’t even see .ja files under sources when I press F12, all I can see is .aspx page and a bunch of 3rd party JavaScript libraries.

Comment: It’s also an old Asp.net website so no debug folder :(

Comment: The lack of a `bin\Debug` folder is irrelevant. That's for server-side code, not client-side code.