# temporarily Stop Bundling and minification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

I am using bundle.config in asp.net mvc but on my local machine every thing was working fine js and css but when i deployed on another machine js and css give me issues, js is not working properly and some css styles are not implemented. so i want to stop Bundling and minification in my project so that i can check the issue either it is only because of bundling or some thing else.
i have searched on it but i didnot get the required result.
In Web.cofig my debugger is true.

> debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"

i have changed the one flag because i was thinking it may help in stop minification.

> BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;

now any one please tell me how to disable bundling for this time so i can enable it later.

Comment: Look out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944745/asp-net-bundles-how-to-disable-minification

Comment: @Dnyanesh thanks man it worked perfectly as i was trying to do.