# How to disable bundling in Visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and .NET framework 4.5.2.
I have tried to disable bundling but it is not getting disabled.

I have made debug attribute true in web.config file. Also tried with:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

I have tried with many cases even putting the above line in `Application_Start()` method and in action executing and in Bundle config.

But if I make debug attribute true and deploy my code to server then bundling gets disabled properly.

I have put the same code in my friend's system but bundling is not getting disabled there either.

I have searched too much but not getting any solution.

If you have faced this problem and got any solution please let me know.

Comment: How do you read the "debug" entry in your web.config?

Comment: I am not reading the debug value from web config. Is there any need to read?

Comment: if you don't read that value and add an IF to the code, how would you expect it to not be executed? maybe you are thinking in "define" directives? if that's the case then you got all wrong, define's are used on the compile phase, you must add them to the build conditional symbols of the project and use #if

Comment: I have found [link|http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944745/asp-net-bundles-how-to-disable-minification] , according to this post we do not need to read debug value