# MVC 5 View Looks Different On Production Server vs IIS Express

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, publish, iis-express

I have a site that is built using c# in MVC5. Everything works fine in testing environment which is hosted on IIS Express. But as soon as I published the site to the proper IIS that will host it online the pages render very differently. Not all css is changed but some is and it seems to effect the js code as well. Here is an example of what the difference looks like between iis express and production.

[image: iis express]
[image: production]
What makes all of this so strange is that there is no error in either Visual studio of the dev console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i cannot figure this out for the life of me.

Comment: Are you bundling css?  If so, it will use the `*.min.css` files instead of `*.css` in a non-debug environment.  If there are differences between the minified and normal versions, this will happen.

Comment: I am bundling css, can I just change the production server to use the full versions and then check them one by one to find the offending party?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944745/asp-net-bundles-how-to-disable-minification