# How to disable automatic minify and compress javascripts files on Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I am using Visual Studio 2013, ASP.MVC Project. When I add a javascript file, for example `fx.js`, the file is minified and new files are created:

`fx.js` (minified)

`fx.js.map`

`fx.js.uncompressed` (original file)

I just want to have the original file without any changes. Because I have a JavaScript Framework with a lot of linked scripts, and the minify format is causing errors with the variables and the paths.

Comment: AFAIK VS 2013 doesn't have any built-in minification support. Aren't you using an extension like [Bundler & Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier) or some task that is being run by the task runner?

Comment: @SamirAguiar It has WebGrease built-in

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944745/asp-net-bundles-how-to-disable-minification) helps.

Comment: @SamirAguiar Thank you, but I already have seen that answer. The conversion occurs when I add the files to the Scripts folder.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround that I found, it is to merge the orignal files after the the minified, to trick Visual Studio that it is working with the minified files.