# MVC C# compilation debug = true still bundling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have a web application MVC5. For a production website we set compilatoin `debug=false` in the web.config. To test this I also did this on my local development machine. This works in production and locally. But now I have to develop further so i need the setting back to compilation `debug=true`. When i set this value and run the application my javascript is stil being bundled. I have also tried `BundleTable.EnableOptimization = false`, but no effect.

**For more information on bundling**, visit [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862)

```
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/main").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/at/main.js",
                    "~/Scripts/at/GridAT.js",
                    "~/Scripts/at/responsive.js",
                    "~/Scripts/at/domainat.js",
                    "~/Scripts/at/fineuploaderat.js",
                    "~/Scripts/at/entitysearch.js",
                    "~/Scripts/at/atquiz.js",
                    "~/Scripts/at/jQueryExtendAT.js",
                    "~/Scripts/at/widget.js"
            ));
```

**In web.config**

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
```

**In Layout:**

```
 <!-- 1. Script: recourses -->
    @Scripts.Render(Url.Content("~/bundles/jquery"))
    @Scripts.Render(Url.Content("~/bundles/jqueryui"))
    @Scripts.Render(Url.Content("~/bundles/jqueryvalidation"))
    @Scripts.Render(Url.Content("~/bundles/resources"))
    @Scripts.Render(Url.Content("~/bundles/fineuploader"))
    @Scripts.Render(Url.Content("~/bundles/highcharts"))
    @Scripts.Render(Url.Content("~/bundles/mustache"))
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js")"></script>
    @Scripts.Render(Url.Content("~/bundles/signalr"))
```

I have also checked with a coworker who does not have this issue on his computer

Comment: You don't explain what you are looking for, nor in your CSHTML you have no reference to `@Scripts.Render(Url.Content("~/bundles/main") ` Could you please change your question to explain 1. What you are experiencing 2. what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: Hello, The issue is that javascript is still being bundles even though web.config setting and BundleTable settings are telling my app not to. I am exxpecting to have bundling disabled with the above settings.

Comment: Have a look at this question: (its nearly a duplicate of your question) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944745/asp-net-bundles-how-to-disable-minification

Comment: for each bundle in bundletable.bundles , bundle.Transforms.Clear() while compilation is in debug mode. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944745/asp-net-bundles-how-to-disable-minification

Comment: implemented:   foreach (var bundle in BundleTable.Bundles)
            {
                bundle.Transforms.Clear();
            }, but no effect

Comment: The Transforms.clear() did disabled minification, but not Bundling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for the rest of the day I decided to remove the project from disk and get it from TFS. After that it worked properly. Thank you all for responding.